# Send email from command line

Tags: excel, vba, command-line, thunderbird

I use Excel VBA to create emails in Thunderbird using command line arguments, found here:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29

Composing the mails works, but how can I send it automatically?

Alternatively, is there a button in Thunderbird to send all composed emails at once?

VBA code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub thunderbird()

Dim strTh As String
Dim strCommand As String

strTh = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe "

strCommand = strCommand & " -compose " & "to=" & Chr(34) & "foo@bar.de" & Chr(34)
strCommand = strCommand & ",preselectid=id2"
strCommand = strCommand & ",subject=" & Chr(34) & "wow so email" & Chr(34)
strCommand = strCommand & ",body=" & Chr(34) & "anything" & Chr(10) & "more" & Chr(34)

Call Shell(strTh & strCommand, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: You can simplify your string concatenation with the line continuation token `_`.

Comment: Thanks. I found this snippet somewhere else and only modified it a little. Will follow your recommendation finally.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible as such. However, https://support.mozilla.org/questions/1144493 lists alternatives, in case they work for you.

From UI, File -> Send Unsent Messages should work (you may need to activate the menu bar) to send all composed messages.